# A question on a Fourier transform "Plancherel-type" identity

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, convolution

Let $\phi, W:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. How can one see that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} W(z-w)\phi(z)\phi(w)dzdw= \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \hat W(\xi) |\hat\phi(\xi)|^2 \tag{1}
$$
holds? (perhaps up to a factor of $2\pi$ or something like that, depending on your convention for the Fourier transform).

I didn't state precisely what my assumptions on $W,\phi$ are; I am fine with assuming whatever suffices here.

I see that
$$
W*\phi(z)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} W(z-w)\phi(w)dw,
$$
so the LHS of $(1)$ equals
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} (W*\phi)(z) \phi(z) dz.
$$
I am not sure how to proceed from here. I thought applying
the  Plancherel identity, but this doesn't seem to give the required result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\phi$ is real-valued.

Plancherel says that
\begin{align*}
\int(W\ast\phi)(z)\overline{\phi(z)}dz=\int\widehat{W\ast\phi}(z)\overline{\widehat{\phi}(z)}dz,
\end{align*}
then
\begin{align*}
\int(W\ast\phi)(z)\phi(z)dz=\int\widehat{W\ast\phi}(z)\overline{\widehat{\phi}(z)}dz=\int\widehat{W}(z)\widehat{\phi}(z)\overline{\widehat{\phi}(z)}dz=\int\widehat{W(z)}|\widehat{\phi}(z)|^{2}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that the Fourier transform is an isometry between Hilbert spaces, so the entire inner product is preserved, not just the norm.